# Is it possible to retain textboxes value after post back in php if they are generated dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to keep textboxes' value after post back in php if they are generated dynamically with jQuery?

Dynamically generated elements like textboxes disappear after post back unless we use client-side validation before submitting the form.

But is it possible to fill values again in those dynamically generated textboxes?

Comment: show what you did and where you got problem

Comment: Yes its certainly possable, if you rebuild your form from the post data

Comment: have you tried using $.post function?

Comment: are you trying something like back button functionality for the dynamically created button?

Comment: oh you all are misguided! sorry. say i have a form in which user generates 5 textboxes dynamically using javascript. he fills up the form but left one or two mandatory field empty. then submits the form without filling them up unknowingly or deliberately. then php validates the form and shows some errors. then form is post back to the same page. the static form fields keep post back value but the text boxes created by javascript or jquery will no longer there and obviously their values will be gone. so how can we retain those values and fill them up again in those corresponding form fields.

Comment: Simply have your PHP script output the form fields with values pre-filled when it generates the code for the “new” page that is shown to the user after server-side validation failed …

Comment: But how will PHP know how many form fields say file input or textbox had been generated by the user while filling up the form? And how to grab those values and fill up in the dynamically generated fields? Can you provide some code example to me or some demo?